legacyScreenSaver taking 67GB on disk -- OK to delete?
I noticed something called "legacyScreenSaver" takes 67GB on disk and feel it’s too much for me.
I looked deeper, and I found that it's actually for the screen saver I do use, Aerial. It's in /Users/[user]/Containers/legacyScreenSaver/Data/Library/Application Support/Aerial/, and 59GB of that 67GB is in a cache
I'm using a different screensaver. OK to delete legacyScreenSaver?

Sure. You can delete those third party cached videos. Or you could tell it how much space you can allow it to consume and it should delete files as needed to meet your budget.

https://aerialscreensaver.github.io/faq.html#CacheSize

As suggested in the comments, make a good backup (maybe you can exclude those files from backup now you know it’s cached from downloads) of everything you’re not sure you can’t delete or know you need to preserve in case you make a mistake deleting the wrong folder.
